# How does Hireling work with Throne Room or King's Court?

Tags: dominion, dominion-prosperity, dominion-adventures

I was playing [Dominion Adventures combined with Prosperity](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Adventures#Adventures_.26_Prosperity), the "Think Big" setup.

The main focus here are these 2 cards:

- King's Court (from Prosperity)

  [image: King's Court]
- Hireling (from Adventures)

  [image: Hireling]

**Now the problem.**
it's my turn and I have in my hand both of the cards above.
**What happens if I play King's Court with Hireling?**

My interpretation is that for the rest of the game, each turn, I draw 3 extra cards.
Can I get a confirmation or a correction on this?

Side notes:

- The same scenario can happen if I play Throne Room from the base game and Hireling. (but with 2 instead of 3).
- I've got this from the [wiki page for the Hireling card](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Hireling):

  > And if you play a Necromancer that plays a Throne Room that plays a Hireling twice, the Necromancer will stay in play for the rest of the game.

The next logic step (my interpretation at least) from here would be that King's Court in my case, stays in play for the rest of the game, but again, I'm not sure since the rule above does not say that "Throne Room" stays in play, only Necromancer.

Comment: I did a bit of searching on the internet, and did not find anything definite about whether or not the Throne Room or King's Court stays in play.

Comment: it does stay in play. see the link in Zibelas answer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [wiki](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Hireling) has this line on Hireling:

> If you use Disciple (or a similar card, like Throne Room) to play
> Hireling twice, you will draw two extra cards each turn, and Disciple
> will also stay in play for the rest of the game.

Since King's Court is the big brother of Throne Room (same wording with just a better effect), from this we can infer that you do get 3 cards and that King's Court stays in play as well.

Comment: I'm glad I got the logic right, but I'm pissed off I didn't get to that wiki page line. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: "little brother" perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

I tried using a Throne Room to play a Hireling twice on https://dominion.games/, and both the Throne Room and the Hireling stayed in play for the whole game.

That seems right to me. The [Dominion Strategy wiki](https://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Throne_Room#Other_rules_clarifications) says "If you use Throne Room to play a Duration card, the Throne Room also stays in play until you discard the Duration card. This enables you to track the fact that the Duration card was played multiple times."